# What does "not" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, negation

Does the sentence in bold mean "if you don't make a lot of money" or "except trying to make a lot of money"?

> "You are caught in this really uncomfortable position. You feel very guilty seeing such poverty and helplessness," added Michelle, the 28-year-old on a six-figure wage. "But what are you supposed to do? **Not make a lot of money?**"

source: http://www.cnbc.com/2017/03/03/facebook-engineers-struggling-with-rents-ask-mark-zuckerberg-for-help.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words in bold are a kind of irony. She means she's not going to lower her salary just because she feels bad for the tough situation others are experiencing.

With this kind of irony, she is saying the opposite of what she means. She's emphasizing that if she were to not make a lot of money, that would not be a solution to other people's problems.